# dx-select-box does not load when there is huge list of data - DevExtreme

Tags: angular, devexpress, devextreme

I have a requirement where the data to be displayed in the select box can be as huge as 8000 records.

Currently when I try to bind the data to a dx-select-box using an array source, the control just crashes and it even hangs my browser.

Is there any way I can virtualize the data binding to load a handful of records at a time?

Note: I am using dev extreme angular2 library with 16.2.5 version

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use the [paginate](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/16_2/ApiReference/Data_Layer/DataSource/Configuration/#paginate) option?

With this option selectbox will be able to render data step by step.

Usage:

```
<dx-select-box
    [dataSource]="data"
    ...
></dx-select-box>
```

TS:

```
import DataSource from 'devextreme/data/data_source';
@Component({
...
})
export class AppComponent {
    ...
    constructor(service: Service) { 
        ...
        this.data = new DataSource({
            paginate: true,
            pageSize: 10,
            store: {
            type: "array",
                data: HUGE_ARRAY,
                key: "ID"
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I already tried using paginate but my store is not an ArrayStore. I want to have the same implementation with Custom Store.

Comment: You can go the same way with `CustomStore`. If you are using `dataSource.paginate` option the `skip` and `take` arguments will be available within the `CustomStore.load` method. I think it's enough to speed up your selectbox.

Comment: This [sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/BHcf4sU4AYEnOMV2wvN1?p=preview) shows it in action